# Writing a 1D function that describes the values on a boundary of a 2D function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, boundary-value-problem

The problem is the following: given the function $f(x,y) = 3x + 2y$ and the domain $D = \{x^2 + 4y^2 \le 4\}$, find the values of $f$ on the boundary.

Here is my approach:

- Rewrite $f$ in polar coordinates.
  $$
  f(x,y) = f(r, \theta) = 3r\cos(\theta)+2r\sin(\theta) = r(3\cos(\theta)+2\sin(\theta))
  $$
- Rewrite the boundary of $D$ in polar coordinates.
  $$
  x^2 + 4y^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 3y^2 = r^2 + 3r^2\sin^2(\theta)=4\\
  r^2(1 + 3\sin^2(\theta))=4\\
  r=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + 3\sin^2(\theta)}}, \theta\in[0, 2\pi]\\
  $$
- Create a new function by plugging in the expression above into $f$.
  $$
  g(\theta) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + 3\sin^2(\theta)}}(3\cos(\theta)+2\sin(\theta)), \theta\in[0, 2\pi]\\
  $$

The correct answer however is
$$
2\sin(\theta) + 6\cos(\theta), \theta\in[0, 2\pi]
$$
Could someone please help me identify my mistake?

Comment: No mistake. Your computation is right. Surely, you don't speak about the same $\theta$ !

Comment: I haven't even considered the possibility that their definition of $\theta$ could be different than mine but it makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: See de La Hire's point construction on wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#:~:text=The%20radius%20is%20the%20distance,3%20%E2%88%92%20y%20%E2%88%98%20)%202%20.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. If instead of using a single radius $r$, we use two radii: $a, b$, we could create a "stretched" polar coordinates by mapping $(x, y) \rightarrow (a\cos(\theta), b\sin(\theta))$. So the boundary will become $a^2\cos^2\theta+4b^2\sin^2\theta=4$. Solving for $a, b$ we get $a=2, b=1$, and then $f(x, y)=f(2\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))=6\cos(\theta) + 2\sin(\theta)$! Thank you again for your guidance JeanMarie & MathLover !